# How to pull a SQL Table entry based on highest IDENTITY entry and update two columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm not well versed in SQL operations, and would like some help with a task I need to complete in code. I have written a cloud based app that accesses a SQL table containing test results - device ID's, serial numbers, test results etc.

There is a use-case where someone in the field would activate a menu where an update to this table occurs. When the device test result table is updated, I want to store the OLD information in a device test history table. This way, we can go back and see what was changed over time.

So I need to pull all the columns from the `TestedDevice` table, insert them into `TestedDeviceHistory` table, and include some additional information; the current date and the operator's id. (these are two new columns found only in `TestedDeviceHistory`)

At first, I'm using a `SELECT INTO` command, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.TestedDevicesHistory 
FROM dbo.TestedDevices 
WHERE CertificateID = @cert
```

Then I'm attempting this (obviously broken) SQL command:

```
UPDATE dbo.TestedDeviceHistory 
SET Caller = @caller, 
    RecordDate = @date 
WHERE DeviceHistoryID = MAX(DeviceHistoryID)
```

Notes:

1. `DeviceHistoryID` is an `IDENTITY` integer column, so it's unique for each entry made in the history table.
2. `CertificateID` is unique in the `TestedDevices` table. It is expected NOT to be unique in the history table.
3. The code is written in C# 4.5

Maybe this is a case for a stored procedure, which I have never attempted to create or use. Or, perhaps the use of a cursor? Don't know!  This is why I'm humbly asking for the more experienced with SQL to help :)

Comment: You should be able to do `SELECT [PARAMS][...] INTO SOMETABLE INNER|OUTER JOIN OTHERTABLE ON SOMETABLE.SOMETHING = OTHERTABLE.SOMETHING WHERE SOMETABLE.Constraints = SOMETHING` but without knowing how you are getting those other fields values cannot give a more thorough answer. Also, yes a stored proc is a good thing to have, but stored proc versus inline SQL doesn't affect the behavior of the SQL query. It is a good idea to move to one after you have the query working as it should.

Comment: Source table has unique column - CertificateID. Destination table has all the same column names as source table, except it also has two additional column names. What I understand from your suggestion is that there needs to be a third (temporary?) table involved?  Just need to insert everything from Source table into destination table based on CertificateID, THEN add current date and operator ID to destination table.

Comment: No, the inner|outer join is a way to walk to the other table- you have those two fields in destination table that need to be populated, that populated data needs to come from somewhere. If your tables have relationships defined you can walk to the other tables, and then get those fields values with the joins. Typically you will use `INNER JOIN` s.

Comment: Ok, alykins. I'll go try this and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear on if you only want to assign the Caller and RecordDate to the most recent record, or if it could be assigned to all the history records.

For all records, I believe you can do something like

```
SELECT *, @caller AS Caller, @date AS RecordDate INTO dbo.TestedDevicesHistory
FROM dbo.TestedDevices WHERE CertificateID=@cert
```

Comment: This should be a comment- hypothesized answers are generally frowned upon- the OP needs to elaborate.

Comment: Not sure how I should go about fixing this. Delete this and add it as a comment?

Comment: Yep- I would do quickly before someone downvotes it xD

Comment: No, that would be disastrous because this is a rolling history of all changes to a given certificateID - each entry in the history table should reflect the unique date/time and operator who made the change(s).  It's a History of events table - each time a change is made, we want to know: WHAT, WHO and WHEN. As you might see, changes made last week would be a separate entry - we don't want to overwrite the date or operator ID for those changes.

Comment: Yes, but the OP responded saying it isn't what is needed or looking for- I won't downvote you, but that is a recipe for downvote hammers.

Comment: I assumed from your post that when you add entries to the history table, you have the caller and date info at that time. This would take that information and add it in as you are inserting records into the history table, but would not overwrite any previous entries in the history table.

Comment: @Redgum, If those fields are supposed to be populated with those parameters, then yes this is what you would want. It is a little unclear if those values are coming from a relationship with another table, or parameters though. AtCaller AS CALLER will make a field named 'CALLER' for all records returned (as well as recordDate), if that is supposed to happen, then this should work, and you can ignore walking to other tables (although, you may want in your free time to look into table relationships and joins as they are very useful) Note: I had to name it AtCaller bc of tagging.

Comment: quick update - I'm just about there testing. Visual Studio is taking forever to update the database views for some reason. Must be an Azure thing.

Comment: Mrgh. "Statement 'SELECT INTO' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. "   Someone just shoot me. Now. Thanks. (Edit: In my original post I thought I'd mentioned this was running as an Azure service, but apparently it was edited out before I posted.)

Comment: This solution works for non-Azure SQL instances. Unfortunately, in my case, it's an AZURE SQL instance so what I ended up having to do is first query the `TestedDevice` table, read the results into an `object[]` var, then populate my next SQL command with the results from the first query and add the `CallerID` and `RecordDate` data. Ultimately it boils down to two SQL calls instead of one. Thanks all.